# jupyter to latex, why inline images are not exported

Tags: image, latex, jupyter-notebook

I want to convert jupyter notebook to latex, I use jupyter-nbconvert in command line (windows 10) but images aren't included

how to have the embedded images with `![title](image.jpg)` are used when converting notebook jupyter to latex?